# Merging overlapping rectangle with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm using two Haar cascade algorithms (frontal and profile) with OpenCV at the same time to improve the face detection.

Unfortunately, the detection is not working correctly and I don't know how to fix it. The return value is 2 (on a picture with 5 faces, normally detected) and all the rectangles have disappeared.

This is the expected result (without the overlapping rectangles):

[image]

[This is the original picture (and also the result.jpg) if you want to make your own test.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC2ub.jpg)

This is the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread("/home/pi/Downloads/test.jpg")
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
profil_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface_alt.xml")

gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.06, 5)
profil=profil_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

combined_array=np.append(face, profil, axis=0)
combined_list=combined_array.tolist()
result=cv2.groupRectangles(combined_list,2)

print("I've found "+str(len(result))+ " face(s)")

for (x,y,w,h) in result[0]:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Download/result.jpg", image)
```

Comment: found the original [picture](http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/pM0hbj9nivyCHKkM6JmxFMea3qR.jpg). Please add it to the question

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i've done it :)

Comment: The code is still not reproducible, because the `CascadeClassifier('filepath')` is trying to load a classifier from a file which is not available to the users of SO. Also, you may want to upload the `result.jpg` image that appears after the execution, to show the comparison with the one you want. Anyways it is well possible that you are using a pre-trained model that is not as effective as you think.

Comment: You're right, I've made the change. I have not think about that because i'm using the classic haarcascade algorythms that are integrated with OpenCV, but it's a good point to add this information

Comment: What I meant is, it is very likely that the unexpected output that you receive depends on the model that you are loading. We don't have access to `"/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"`, se we cannot test/debug your code. You will either have to publish it, and let us load it in this manner, or find a website where it is available and let us load it from there. The issue otherwise cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Search for NMS.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll check this but i'm afraid to get the same problem that i've described in my new answer (overlapping rectangle disappear... but also non-overlap rectangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, **i've partially solved the problem**.

I've changed the *Threshold* and *EPS* of `result=cv2.groupRectangles` and I've also make a subtraction in `print` function between the number of total faces detected (in *combined_list*) and the number of overlapping detection (return by *result*)

Here's the new code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread("/home/pi/Downloads/test.jpg")
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
profil_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface_alt.xml")

gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.06, 5)
profil=profil_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

combined_array=np.append(face, profil, axis=0)
combined_list=combined_array.tolist()
result=cv2.groupRectangles(combined_list,1,0.85)

print("I've found "+str(len(combined_list)-str(len(result[1]))+ " face(s)")

for (x,y,w,h) in result[0]:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Download/result.jpg", image)
```

[The overlapping rectangles have disappear... but also the other rectangles !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De3sS.jpg)

**Finally, the program give me the correct number of face (5) and redraw overlapping rectangle (that's good news), but the non-overlapping rectangles have disappear...**

I've tried to solve this by using a `np.subtract` between the coordinate from *combined_list* and *result*, then draw the missing rectangle with `for (x,y,w,h) in np.subtract[0]` but it didn't work. **The reason is that the coordinate point of overlapping rectangle are directly recalculate, so i can't make the subtraction with the original coordinate points**

If someone has a idea to solve this issue, don't hesitate :)

Answer (score 1):

The Non Maximum Suppression algorithm is used to solve the problem of overlapping detection results. [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) has a very good article on it and code to get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The openCV function groupRectangles requires 3 inputs.

1) rectList : Vector of rectangles

2) groupthreshold : **Minimum possible number of rectangles minus 1**

3) eps : Relative difference between sides of the rectangles to merge them into a group

Your code:

```
   result=cv2.groupRectangles(combined_list,1,0.85)
```

From your code you have set the groupthreshold  parameter as 1 which rejects all clusters that has one rectangle. Set this parameter as 0 and you should get the result you wanted.

Solution:

```
   result=cv2.groupRectangles(combined_list,0,0.85)
```

Detailed explanation given below:
(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html#ga3dba897ade8aa8227edda66508e16ab9)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, that make sense but unfortunately it doesn't work :o When I make the change, i've got all the rectangle (but also the overlapping rectangle)

Comment: that might because your eps value are not high enough. groupRectangles is a function designed to cluster the rectangles. If the result is not returning the value you wanted, you might need to consider changing the input parameter values.